# How do I get a Potent Aspect?

Tags: reus

Maybe I have overseen it in the Tutorial, but how exactly do I get a Potent Aspect?
What governs the creation of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than one way

The most common is definitely the Forest Giant's Fertility Boost ability. If you place an Aspect on a square while the fertility boost is active on that square, there is a high chance it will be a Potent Aspect.

The Water Giant's Moonsoon ability works the same way, however it needs to be unlocked before you can use it, and it covers a range of squares instead of just one.

You can also find naturally boosted spaces at the start of the game. Just look around for the faint up-arrows above a space. When you click on the space, you'll see a green icon that tells you the space has Level 1 Fertility on it for 10 minutes.

And there is a chance to get a Potent aspect anytime you place one. The starting chance is 25%, however if you have a higher level aspect, you have a better chance at getting a Potent or better aspect.

Comment: Version 1.0.4 changed the starting chance from 25% to 33%.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fertilize the ground with your forest or water giant before you cast an aspect. That enhances the aspect and makes it a potent aspect, or, if you have the ability, it makes it a greater or sublime aspect.

Comment: The tooltip says that, even without fertilization, there's a 25% chance of getting a potent aspect. Is that correct? (I always fertilize beforehand if it's important enough, and otherwise don't pay much attention)

Comment: Yes, it can happen randomly, but for some upgrades you need potent, greater or sublime apsects, so you can't rely on a random chance.